# Can I use the document field as value when building Mongo queries?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following MongoDB collection.

```
[{A:1, B:2}, {A:1, B:1}]
```

Is there a way to use the property "B" something as the following?

```
db.myCollection.find({A: '$B'})
```

I read that there is an approach that calculates the diff of A and B, but what I really want to know is if I can reference document fields when matching documents. This is important for me to understand what I can do and what I cannot do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a quick way of doing this. If you want to do it, you can specify a custom [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) though, for example:

```
db.myCollection.find({"$where": "this.A == this.B"})
```

As noted in the manual though, this will require running that Javascript code for *every* record in the collection, so this won't be the fastest query in the world.